# How can I use emotion/styled in my react project on codepen?

Tags: reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I need to be able to use @emotion/styled CSS-in-JS library so I can pass props to the background-color and color properties of my Button component. The background-color and color of the buttons are supposed to change with the rest of the app.

The commented out section that starts the JS section:

```
import EmotionStyled from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@emotion/styled@11.10.5";
import styled from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@emotion/styled@11.10.5"

function Button(props) {
  const Button = styled.button`
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color: ${props.colorChange};
    color: white;
    border: none;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
    &:hover {
      background-color: ${props.colorChange};
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
  `
 
  return (
    <div className='buttons'>
      <div className='left'>
        <Button><a href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=%22Everything%20has%20beauty%2C%20but%20not%20everyone%20can%20see.%22%20Confucius' id='tweet-quote'
        target='_blank'
        rel='noreferrer'><i className="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></Button>
        <Button><a href='https://www.tumblr.com/login?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fwidgets%2Fshare%2Ftool%3Fposttype%3Dquote%26tags%3Dquotes%252Cfreecodecamp%26caption%3DConfucius%26content%3DEverything%2Bhas%2Bbeauty%252C%2Bbut%2Bnot%2Beveryone%2Bcan%2Bsee.%26canonicalUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.tumblr.com%252Fbuttons%26shareSource%3Dtumblr_share_button' id='tumblr-quote'
        target='_blank'
        rel='noreferrer'><i className="fa-brands fa-tumblr"></i></a></Button>
      </div>
      <Button id='new-quote'
      onClick={props.handleChange}
      >New quote</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

is supposed to replace the Button component I have in place at the moment. Whenever I use this emotion-styled Button component, everything goes blank. Please help!

Here is a link to the codepen project: https://codepen.io/lawlessIndi/pen/gOKjNMG.